# Why are these cards not getting filtered and floating left?

Tags: javascript, html, css

These cards have their `class` updated, but they don't get filtered and float to the left.

```js
      let btnDiv = document.getElementById('filterBtnContainer');
      let btns = btnDiv.querySelectorAll('.btn');
      btns.forEach((btn, i) => {
        let btnValue = `q${i}`;
        btn.classList.add('btn', 'filter');
        btn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
        btn.setAttribute('value', btnValue);
        btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
          filterSelection(btnValue);
        });
      });

      //filterSelection('q0');

      function filterSelection(c) {
        console.log(c)
        let cardContainer = document.getElementById('cardsContainer');
        var x, i;
        x = cardContainer.getElementsByClassName("card");
        if (c == 'q0') c = "";

        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
          removeClass(x[i], "show");
          if (x[i].className.indexOf(c) > -1) addClass(x[i], "show");
        }
      }

      // Show filtered elements
      function addClass(element, name) {
        var i, arr1, arr2;
        arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
        arr2 = name.split(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
          if (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) == -1) {
            element.className += " " + arr2[i];
          }
        }
      }

      // Hide elements that are not selected
      function removeClass(element, name) {
        var i, arr1, arr2;
        arr1 = element.className.split(" ");
        arr2 = name.split(" ");
        for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
          while (arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]) > -1) {
            arr1.splice(arr1.indexOf(arr2[i]), 1);
          }
        }
        element.className = arr1.join(" ");
      }
```

```css
  .card {
  background-color: #fafafa;
  font-size: 12px;
  border-radius: 5px !important;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24) 0px 3px 8px;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 7px;
  flex-direction: inherit !important;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform: scale(1);
  display: none;
}

.card:hover {
  transform: scale(1.01);
}

.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 190px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.show {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div id="filterBtnContainer">
  <button class="btn filter active" type="submit" value="q0">All</button>
  <button class="btn filter" type="submit" value="q1">Q1</button>
  <button class="btn filter" type="submit" value="q2">Q2</button>
  <button class="btn filter" type="submit" value="q3">Q3</button>
  <button class="btn filter" type="submit" value="q4">Q4</button>
  </div>
<div id="cardsContainer">
  <div class="row crd-group">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
      <div class="form-group row p-1 p-md-1 m-2 m-md-1 card q2 show">
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="quarter" value="2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="month" value="2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="weekNum" value="3">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" selected="">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="2023-02-02"></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="status">Status:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="status" value="Planned">
            <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
            <option value="Published">Published</option>
            <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="status">Image URL:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" name="img-link" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg"><a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" class="card-img"></a></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="post">Post:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control post" name="post">Lorem Ipsum</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" target="_blank" style="cursor: pointer;"><label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
        </a>
        <input type="text" class="form-control published-link-input" name="published-link" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" hidden=""><label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postNum" value="1"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
      <div class="form-group row p-1 p-md-1 m-2 m-md-1 card q2 show">
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="quarter" value="2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="month" value="2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="weekNum" value="2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="2023-02-02"></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="status">Status:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="status" value="Planned">
            <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
            <option value="Published">Published</option>
            <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="status">Image URL:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" name="img-link" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg"><a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" class="card-img"></a></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="post">Post:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control post" name="post">Lorem Ipsum</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" target="_blank" style="cursor: pointer;"><label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
        </a>
        <input type="text" class="form-control published-link-input" name="published-link" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" hidden="">
        <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postNum" value="2">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
      <div class="form-group row p-1 p-md-1 m-2 m-md-1 card q2 show">
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="quarter">Quarter:</label><select class="form-control" name="quarter" value="2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="month" value="2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="weekNum" value="4">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4" selected="">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="2023-02-02"></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="status">Status:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="status" value="Planned">
            <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
            <option value="Published">Published</option>
            <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="status">Image URL:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" name="img-link" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg"><a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" class="card-img"></a></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="post">Post:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control post" name="post">Lorem Ipsum</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" target="_blank" style="cursor: pointer;"><label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
        </a>
        <input type="text" class="form-control published-link-input" name="published-link" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" hidden=""><label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postNum" value="3">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-md-6 col-xl-3">
      <div class="form-group row p-1 p-md-1 m-2 m-md-1 card q2 show">
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="quarter">Quarter:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="quarter" value="2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="monthNum">Month:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="month" value="2">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2" selected="">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="weekNum">Week:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="weekNum" value="3">
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3" selected="">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-6 mt-3"><label for="date">Date:</label>
        <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" value="2023-02-02"></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="status">Status:</label>
        <select class="form-control" name="status" value="Planned">
            <option value="Planned" selected="">Planned</option>
            <option value="Published">Published</option>
            <option value="Cancelled">Cancelled</option>
          </select></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="status">Image URL:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control imgLink" name="img-link" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg"><a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" target="_blank"><img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" class="card-img"></a></div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><label for="post">Post:</label>
        <textarea class="form-control post" name="post">Lorem Ipsumdale-az/</textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 mt-3"><a href="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg" target="_blank" style="cursor: pointer;">
        <label for="publishedPostLink">Published Link:</label>
        </a>
        <input type="text" class="form-control published-link-input" name="published-link" value="https://images.pexels.com/photos/170811/pexels-photo-170811.jpeg">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group" hidden="">
        <label for="postNum">Post Number:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="postNum" value="4">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You probably should be using the `classList` API instead of rolling your own version of those tools.

Answer (score 1):

That is because your own styles are overriden by the bootstrap styles you have included in your page.

You need to put your styles after the bootstrap ones.

In general they should have higher specificity either by more specific selectors or if they share the same specificity, they should come later in your page.

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity#selector_weight_categories for more details.

Comment: Thanks! Kind of overwhelmed as a beginner by the complexity (to me). It'll take me a while to digest.